# node.js - using weld with express?

Tags: html, node.js, express, templating

I'm new to node.js, and attempting to use [weld](https://github.com/hij1nx/weld) to render templates on the server-side and using express as the router.

However the examples for node.js doesn't show serving the content, and am fuzzy on how this would work with express:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.env(
  './test.html', 
  ['./jquery.js', './weld.js'],
  function(errors, window) {
    var data = [{ name: 'hij1nx',  title : 'code slayer' },
              { name: 'tmpvar', title : 'code pimp' }];
    window.weld(window.$('.contact')[0], data);
  }
);
```

Help or example would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen this before. Not sure how I feel about it..

Comment: Yeah I'd like to get this working for node, as it's similar to Wicket's approach, which I really liked for Java apps.

Comment: Plates (also by nodejitsu) is the new Weld: https://github.com/flatiron/plates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this would work. Haven't tested though.

```
var fs = require('fs'), 
    jsdom = require('jsdom'),
    app = require('express').createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    jsdom.env('./test.html', ['./jquery.js', './weld.js'], function(errors, window) {
        var data = [{
            name : 'hij1nx',
            title : 'code slayer'
        }, {
            name : 'tmpvar',
            title : 'code pimp'
        }];
        window.weld(window.$('.contact')[0], data);
        res.send(window.document.innerHTML); //after the welding part we just send the innerHTML
        window.close();  // to prevent memory leaks of JSDOM
    });

});
app.listen(3001);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, works great.  Appreciated and accepted. Though one minor question is why the need for [0] index?  I assumed this was jQuery, which doesn't require the index for selectors that return one value.

Comment: I'm not an experienced user with JQuery and not so sure why, but for both class selectors and id selectors it returns and array, even though they could be one.